# Bootstrap modal not shown on first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use a bootstrap 3.0 modal to load external html file into a modal using jQuery Ajax loader, however it's not shown on first call but works on subsequent calls.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true">Department</a>

<div class="contianer">
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" width="150" alt="SmartAdmin">
                </h4>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body no-padding">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myModal').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "?AId=DEPT_ADDUPDATE",
        data: { },
        success: function(data){
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try remove `id="myModal"` from the `<a >` tag? You assigned the same id `myModal` to two different elements

Comment: i tried remove and also change id="myModalss" like this..  still i had same error..

Comment: i tried inspect element on browser shown this error: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."

Comment: still had same error..... plzzzzzz

Comment: while my first call "<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>" shown still this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
success: function(data){
        $('.modal-body').html(data);
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
    }
```

Comment: datt-target="#myModal" to data-target="#myModal"

Comment: i rewrite my answer) check it please